# Spring 4 properties file doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, properties

I've tried to replace hardcoded db settings in the bean config to db.properties file like that:

```
@Configuration
public class BeansConfig {

  private @Value("#{database['db.url']}") String dbURL;

   public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClass("something");
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(dbURL);
    dataSource.setUser("something")
    dataSource.setPassword("something")
    return dataSource;
   }
 }
```

But it doesnt' work. And it's highlighted, I can Ctrl-Click on it and it'll get me to the .properties file.
But when I'm starting app, it just doesn't work. It's trying to get to DB but it doesn't. When I'm changing **dbURL** on "url" itself it work smoothly.

Tried lot's of guides but it didn't helped.

**EDIT**

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:*/appSecurity.xml
        classpath:*/appContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:*/appContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Note that it'll be assigned only *after* the constructor has finished. If you're checking the `dbURL` value before the constructor, it'll be `null`.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun just like hardcoded string, right?

Comment: did you add `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean?

Comment: @sidgate yep

    <util:properties id="database" location="classpath:/properties/database.properties"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/properties/database.properties" />

Comment: is your xml config loaded before java config?

Comment: @sidgate how to check that?)

Comment: how have you configured XML configuration and java configuration? in web.xml? if yes, plz share it. Also check if `"${db.url}"` is working

Comment: @sidgate posted web.xml. "${db.url}" doesn't work also.

Comment: @ottercoder Try annotating your class with `@PropertySource("classpath:yourConfigFileOnClasspath.properties")` and the field with `@Value("${db.url}")`. This is how I get property values in my application

Comment: Agree with Tomas Kralik - I do it exactly the same way.

Comment: @TomasKralik yeah, like I said, I tried lots of methods. This one don' t work as well.(

Comment: @ottercoder You also need to define `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean. Annotate the class with `@Configuration` and add the following method/bean `@Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfig() {
  return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }` I do not see a reason for this not to work. You could also edit the OP with your context configuration XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have,

`db.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/livedump` in your properties file(It has to be `application.properties` or annotate the class with `@PropertySource("classpath:name_of_file.properties")`).

you can do,

```
@Value("${db.url}")
String dbURL;
```

Comment: @Value("${db.url}") highlighting also, but it doesn't help.